# Replace values in python pandas column based on second df

Tags: python, pandas, replace, syntax

I have gone through all similar questions on stackoverflow, but the solutions still don't work for me.

I have two dfs:

```
df1:
User_ID |    Code_1
123           htrh
345           NaN
567           cewr
...

df2:
User_ID |    Code_2
123           ert
345           nad
```

I want to replace df1.Code_1 with df2.Code_2 based on User_ID. Please note that df2 is a subset of df1's user_ids.

I tried this

```
df1['Code_1'] = df1['User_ID'].replace(df2.set_index('User_ID')['Code_2'])
```

and I tried this

```
df1.loc[df1.User_ID.isin(df2.User_ID), ['Code_1']] = df2[['Code_2']]
```

and both didn't work.Nothing changed.

Expected Output:

```
df1:
    User_ID |    Code_1
    123           ert
    345           nad
    567           cewr
    ...
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

```
df1['Code_1'] = df1['User_ID'].map(df2.set_index('User_ID')['Code_2'])\
                              .fillna(df1['Code_1'])

print(df1)

#    User_ID Code_1
# 0      123    ert
# 1      345    nad
# 2      567   cewr
```

The idea is to align indices when you perform the mapping and fill with original values if no mapping exists in `df2`.

Comment: To me it looks like pd.DataFrame.update is made exactly for what is asked, is simpler to understand, can update multiple columns at once, and can be used more generally due to the presence of parameters.

Comment: @mcard, your answer is good, I upvoted it. I think which answer gets chosen is as much personal preference as anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataFrame.update`. The id columns (`User_ID`) and the code columns (`Code_1`, `Code_2`) should have the same name across the dataframes before calling the function.

```
df2.columns = ['User_ID', 'Code_1']
df1.update(df2)
```

That should be enough for your case. For other uses, consult the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use combine_first

```
df2.set_index('User_ID').Code_2.combine_first(df1.set_index('User_ID').Code_1)


User_ID
123     ert
345     nad
567    cewr
```